# jsapi is not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-visualization, jsapi

```
<script src="../BootStrapFiles/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    // google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetChartData',
            data: '{}',
            success:
            function (response) {
                drawchart(response.d);
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data!");
            }
        });
    })
    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Total amount');
        //   data.addColumn('string', 'Total amount2');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            // data.addRows([dataValues[i].Year, dataValues[i].Total], dataValues[i].Year);
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].Year, dataValues[i].Total]);
        }

        //   new google.visualization.PieChart
        //  new google.visualization.BarChart(  //LineChart  //ColumnChart  //ComboChart
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChartDivPie')).
        draw(data, { title: "Sales Pie chart last 8 days " });

        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('myChartDiv')).
        draw(data, { title: "Sales Column chart last 8 days " });

    }  
</script>
```

This is my code when i run on visual studio 2010 it runs perfect . but when try to run on visual studio 2015 chart does not appear .Can you please help me what i am doing wrong in it .Is it is version problem or something else ? my code was developed in visual studio 2010 .every things is working perfect but charts are not visible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first**: there is a `callback` associated with the `load` statement

you shouldn't try to use the `google.visualization` namespace, until after the `callback` has fired...

see following snippet...

```
<script src="../BootStrapFiles/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
      // set callback
      callback: getData,
      packages: ['corechart']
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // load google first
    function getData() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          url: 'Default.aspx/GetChartData',
          data: '{}',
          success:
          function (response) {
              drawchart(response.d);
          },

          error: function () {
              alert("Error loading data!");
          }
      });
    }
    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Total amount');
        //   data.addColumn('string', 'Total amount2');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            // data.addRows([dataValues[i].Year, dataValues[i].Total], dataValues[i].Year);
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].Year, dataValues[i].Total]);
        }

        //   new google.visualization.PieChart
        //  new google.visualization.BarChart(  //LineChart  //ColumnChart  //ComboChart
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChartDivPie')).
        draw(data, { title: "Sales Pie chart last 8 days " });

        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('myChartDiv')).
        draw(data, { title: "Sales Column chart last 8 days " });

    }
</script>
```

---

**next**: recommend using `loader.js`, rather than `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader` from now on.

it appears the library has been downloaded to a local folder

the newer library can be found here...

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will only change the `load` statement...

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
      // set callback
      callback: getData,
      packages: ['bar']
    });
```

Comment: thank you soo much @whiteHat . that works for me .thanks alot again .

Comment: #whitehat i wish i could :D but i cnt unfortunately